# How to code in save button?

Tags: c#

I Have used five text box and i want to save all contents in textbox into a single file with save  button using C#.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

Comment: And what did you try? Why do you need all text change  events?

Comment: Add the texts (string output = textBox1.Text + "\r\n" + ..., or maybe with a environment.newline and then do a File.WriteAllText()! (Include System.IO!)

Answer (score -1):

I would save as xml to make it easier to read.  Using a DataSet makes reading and writing xml easy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\text.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Data Set");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Data");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Text Box 1", textBox1.Text });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Text Box 2", textBox2.Text });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Text Box 3", textBox3.Text });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Text Box 4", textBox4.Text });

            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

            //use following to read
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);
            textBox1.Text = ds.Tables["Data"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == "Text Box 1").Select(x => x.Field<string>("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
            textBox2.Text = ds.Tables["Data"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == "Text Box 2").Select(x => x.Field<string>("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
            textBox3.Text = ds.Tables["Data"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == "Text Box 3").Select(x => x.Field<string>("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
            textBox4.Text = ds.Tables["Data"].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == "Text Box 4").Select(x => x.Field<string>("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
        }


    }
}
​
```

Comment: What on earth makes you think that XML is a) easy to read in the first place or b) useful/appropriate for the contents of the textboxes??? The OP asks for 1 or 2 lines of code.

Comment: It is only one instruction with dataset method to read an xml file.   The parsing is a different issue.  Much more robust to read an xml file than a straight text file.

Comment: This entirely depends on context. Which we don't have. What I see is a total newbie who probably simply needs to learn about System.IO.File methods..